# Arabic fonts is not inserting in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, encoding, arabic

i am trying to insert arabic fonts from a website to mysql database using python 
the fonts in showing correctly as arabic in console but when it insert into database, there 
it is not show correctly and when i want to try to show it in our web page there also 
Like "Ø¨Ø±Ø¬ Ø§Ù„Ø¯ÙˆÙ" 
i also change charset to Utf-8 General_ci/utf_8 unicode of my database/schema and table column 
and  also add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to my web page in which i wanna show these arabic fonts but still same problem, any one have an idea !

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using Arabic fonts then i think the charset `iso-8859-6` will work. I've never worked with Arabic fonts, but UTF-8 is only supposed to work for languages with Latin letters and extra ASCII characters. I do not know if Arabic is a part of UTF-8. Try `iso-8859-6`!

Comment: i am using arabic and English fonts both, it will not work for English font

Comment: *All* ISO 8859 characters are capable of being encoded as UTF-8 since they're found in Unicode.

Comment: Did some research on it, seems like UTF-8 can handle both Latin and Arabic fonts :D Keep the `charset=utf-8` in your meta tag. What kind of databse do you use? You might have to update it to UTF-8 as it's not using that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using `unicode` for your values, not `str`.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (?)', ('あいうえお',))   # WRONG
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (?)', (u'あいうえお',))  # RIGHT
```

Comment: if i have data_in_var for inserting then,             cursor.execute('INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES (?)',(UVar,))?     also if i have more then one variables!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the encoding is getting jacked up somewhere along the way.  You should be saving the information in the database as Unicode, as Ignacio said. Then, when you display it in your webpage, you need to encode the text as utf-8.

How you do this will depend on what language you're using.  In python it would be `content.encode('utf-8')` , where "content" is the variable for whatever text you're getting from the database.